# Sitecore Indexing based off of base template

Tags: templates, indexing, sitecore

I am making a custom index but I need it to only index items that have a certain base template or has a certain template name.
I added the base template ID to "include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate"" but that only uses exact template ID matching and it doesn't allow template names.
I am guessing I need to override something but not sure where to start. This is on Sitecore 8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find what you need here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/02/custom-indexes-in-sitecore-habitat.html

> For the included templates in the document options I was searching for
>   another solution so I decided to throw my question on the Sitecore
>   Slack Helix/Habitat channel and ended up in a discussion with Thomas
>   Eldblom and Sitecore junkie Mike Reynolds. Thomas came up with the
>   idea to hook into the index process to enable it to include base
>   templates and Mike kept pushing me to do it and so.. I wrote an
>   extension to configure your index based on base templates.

It's custom code that allows you to define this in your index config:

```
<include hint="list:AddIncludedBaseTemplate">
    <BaseTemplate1>{...}</BaseTemplate1>
</include>
```

Comment: Updated link URL: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/02/custom-indexes-in-sitecore-habitat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this as standard in Sitecore 10 (maybe 9?)

```
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
    <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">

        <include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate">
            <SomeName>{...your_base_template_id...}</SomeName>
        </include>
    
        <checkTemplateInheritance>true</checkTemplateInheritance>
    </documentOptions>
</configuration>
```